# Cannot retrieve parenthesis value from url in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a problem a problem with retrieving parenthesis value from url. I am developing a PHP project using CodeIgniter Framework.

I have a mvc url format like this - http://localhost/controller/action/id/name

Then I passed the value like this - http://localhost/controller/action/2/test%20(test)

And like this as well - Then I passed the value like this:

> http://localhost/controller/action/2/test+(test)

So my action function is like this with parameters-

```
function action($id,$name)
{
   $name = urldecode($name)
   //I find the index of start "t"
   echo strpos($name,'t'); //this is working find
   echo strpos($name,'('); // this is outputing nothing
   echo $name; // this is outputing test (test)
}
```

What is the problem ? Why cannot I find index of "(". Actually I and retrieving record from database using that value. But parenthesis is not working well with php. I showing output correctly. But cannot find index of it.

Comment: use str_replace function to replace the parentheses. str_replace("Specifies the value to find","Specifies the value to replace the value in find","Specifies the string to be searched");

Comment: This give me same result. No difference

Comment: PHP is not treating it like "(" . When I find like this str_replace('(','+',$name) . Nothing was changed in the string.

Comment: You code outputs: `142http://localhost/controller/action/2/test (test)`. I suspect there is more going on. Try just running the code you posted (with the addition of a semicolon after `$name = urldecode($name)`

Comment: @Waiyan str_replace is working because I tried this example http://phpfiddle.org/. Copy and paste the code there and you will see the output

Comment: Nope `str_replace` is not the correct function to work around over here instead you need `urlencode` and `urldecode`

Comment: Yes I did urlencode and decode . But the problem is when I output it using echo . Paranthesis are shown. But when I use it with strpos(). It is not treated as '(' . I think maybe parathesis is replaced with some internal code internally. Is that possible ?

Comment: @Waiyan Check out I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. That is the issue with Codeigniter Framework. I replaced all "(" and ")" with "[" and "]" before urlencoding. Then I replaced all "[" and "]" with "(" and ")" after urldecoding. You will get the answer after you read this article. http://qubitlogs.com/PHP/2013/01/24/parentheses-in-urls-not-working-codeigniter-datamapper-orm/ . Thank everyone for helping me.

Comment: That's what the actual solution is

Comment: That was because of Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$url = 'localhost/melomap_music/singers/details/760/test%20(test)';
$string = urldecode($url);
$pattern1 = '/[)]/';
$pattern2 = '/[(]/';
preg_match($pattern1, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
preg_match($pattern2, $string, $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$start = $matches2[0][1]; //49
$end = $matches[0][1]; //54
?>
```

Comment: returning empty array

Comment: Sorry . I replied wrong. No. It is not working. Parenthesis are not replaced when it came from url. I also used urldecode on it.

Comment: @Waiyan paste the url and I will provide the solution to replace

Comment: strpos($name,'(') is returning nothing.

Comment: @Waiyan So actually you want retrieve the (test) value from url

Comment: Then I want to find the index of "(" and ")"

Comment: U got solution please ?

Comment: Oh just a moment please

Comment: It is working fine when i pass url. But when i pass name . It is not working . I just want to get index of parenthesis from name.Thanks u for ur help.

Comment: It is working fine when I just pass as a string. But when I really retrieve from url. It is not working. $this->uri->segment(4) . Then I pass that value. Not working

Comment: Maybe because of this issue. Please check this out. This is the most possible solution.In next comment

Comment: http://qubitlogs.com/PHP/2013/01/24/parentheses-in-urls-not-working-codeigniter-datamapper-orm/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
<?php
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/',urldecode($name),$a);
echo $a[1];
```

Comment: Returning empty array